# Free gauge control for windows application

Tags: c#, controls, gauge

Quick summary-
               How can i use Gauge controls on my win application

I want to develop windows application with chats and gauges .For that i found chart control for charts ,but don't found gauge control. there is one gauge control which is available for Report Definition Language Client-side report and Show only on report viewer. Also i know the third parties control but they are not free.

Comment: Are you using Windwos Forms or WPF or others?

Comment: I m using windows from not wpf ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this example.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/448721/AGauge-WinForms-Gauge-Control

Hope it will be help.

Comment: The codeproject.com download links no longer appear to work, but I found another source for apparently the same project: http://www.ucancode.net/CSharp_Tutorial_GDI+_Gauge_Source_Code.htm

Answer (score 0):

1-For windows forms: [Aqua Guage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20341/Aqua-Gauge)

2-If you could host WPF controls in Windows Forms and use: [Circular Guage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38361/Circular-gauge-custom-control-for-Silverlight-3-an)

Check the license information to confirm that the above is free.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone needs a free "loading clock" control for WinForms here is the link:
[Download](http://www.bug.hr/forum/topic/programiranje/vasi-programerski-radovi/113640.aspx?page=3&jumpto=4729332&sort=asc&view=flat)

Supports .NET from 2.0 to 4.5.1 (x86 and x64)